# PHP: Returning an array of objects in SOAP

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I've checked and tried other solutions on StackOverflow, however it didn't help me a bit so I decided to ask it once again.

I'm trying to create a SOAP server, printing the resulting WSDL. However everything works other than `array`. No matter what I've done, I couldn't get the server return me a list of `products`. What could be the possible reason?

Here is my code for the function:

```
function getProducts() {
    $productList = array();
for($i=0;$i<5;$i++) {
        array_push($productList, array(
            "pName" => "Hello",
            "pBrand" =>"World"
        ));
    }
    return $productList;           
}
```

Here is the **complex type** definitions and **function** registers;

```
$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'product',
    'complexType',
    'struct',
    'all',
    '',
    array(
        'pName' => array('name' => 'pName', 'type' => 'xsd:string'),
        'pBrand' => array('name' => 'pBrand', 'type' => 'xsd:string'))
);

$server->wsdl->addComplexType(
    'productList',
    'complexType',
    'array',
    '',
    'SOAP-ENC:Array',
    array(),
    array(
        array('ref' => 'SOAP-ENC:arrayType', 
              'wsdl:arrayType' => 'tns:product[]')
    ),
    'tns:product'
);
$server->register('getProducts',
                      array(),
                      array('productListResult' => 'tns:productList'),
                      'urn:QRWebService',
                      'urn:QRWebService#getProducts',
                      'rpc',
                      'encoded'
                      );
```

Comment: Have you checked your client? Just tried your code and it works, Server NuSoap, Client Excel VBA. If you want you can expose your WSDL URL and I can test with my client.

Comment: Oh, maybe your code is not complete, really. My code goes on with

    `$strRawPostData = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $server->service($strRawPostData);`

Comment: It does not work from C#. There is a problem with matching the types of $productList.